# Passing data between UITableViewController to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

I have a problem when try to pass some data between UITableView to UIViewController.
I looking for google and in the stackoverflow, but didn't sucess.

Here the NSLog is printing what I want

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetalhesPosto *detalhesPosto = [[DetalhesPosto alloc]init];

    detalhesPosto.aliasPosto = alias;

    NSLog(@"%@",detalhesPosto.aliasPosto);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detalhesPosto animated:YES];

    [detalhesPosto release];

}
```

when navigationController call a view detalhesPosto a have a code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    labelAliasPosto.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aliasPosto];

    NSLog(@"YES or NO ? %@",aliasPosto);
}
```

but a NSLog is printing => 2012-11-06 18:48:58.061 MAP[7006:f803] YES or NO ? >

Can you halp me please ?

Tks
Paulo

Comment: 2012-11-06 18:48:58.061 MAP[7006:f803] YES or NO ? <UILabel: 0x6a42740; frame = (32 206; 242 72); text = <UILabel: 0x6a42740; fram...; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a43710>>

Comment: Not very clear what the properties "alias and aliasPosto" are.
Looks like "alias" is a UILabel.

Comment: Could you write also declarations like "alias and aliasPosto" ?

Comment: No jajo87 aliasPosto is a String, UILabel is a labelAliasPosto, I want that labelAliasPosto.text received the value setting in detalhesPosto.aliasPosto in UItableView... Tks

Comment: @interface DetalhesPosto : UIViewController{
    UILabel *labelAliasPosto;
    NSString *aliasPosto;
  
    
}

Comment: @interface PostoViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSString *alias;

Comment: You code says that aliasPosta is a label. Please check your code.

Comment: Yes... Tks Ulas...I was blind ... for some reason hed a two references in Files Own to the Label ( aliasPosto and labelAliasPosto). Tks for halp